# interpolating random data to regular grid

Tags: python, interpolation

My data looks like this
[image: Data]

I want to interpolate this to a 4 cell grid. Each cell would just have average values of all the points lying inside it.[image]

The output then should look like this

[image]

Thus we have converted the entire data to a 2x2 matrix. Each cell of this matrix will have average x coordinate & average y coordinate values of all the points lying inside them.

A1= (3,-3) ; A2 = (3.5, 1.5)

A3= (-1,-3) ; A4= (-2,1)

=====WHAT IVE TRIED=====

```
avg = [[
        (
            ( mat[row][col][0]
            + mat[row][col+1][0]
            + mat[row+1][col][0]
            + mat[row+1][col+1][0] ) / 4.0
        , 
            ( mat[row][col][1]
            + mat[row][col+1][1]
            + mat[row+1][col][1]
            + mat[row+1][col+1][1] ) / 4.0
        )
        for col in range(0, len(mat[0]), 2) ]
    for row in range(0, len(mat), 2)
]
```

Comment: Seems simple, what have you tried?

Comment: @jandob I was looking at this https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data.html , but its actually blob rather than average approximation of data onto an "Equally spaced" grids

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the code in it (so it's readable).

Comment: @vinita Never put code in comments on here. Edit the original question to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that good with numpy/scipy, i think this could be vastly improved in terms of elegancy and efficiency, but it works:

[-> jupyter notebook with intermediate plots](https://gist.github.com/jandob/09de6a2f472bf2604d3de700649b66c0)

Final code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
data = np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=(2,100))
dataX = data[0]
dataY = data[1]

#plot the data
plt.plot(data[0], data[1], 'b+')

gridSize = 1.0

# grid coordinates are lower left point of grid rectangles
gridMaxX = math.floor(max(dataX) / gridSize)
gridMaxY = math.floor(max(dataY) / gridSize)
gridMinX = math.floor(min(dataX) / gridSize)
gridMinY = math.floor(min(dataY) / gridSize)

gridX = np.arange(gridMinX,gridMaxX + gridSize, gridSize)
gridY = np.arange(gridMinY,gridMaxY + gridSize, gridSize)

#plot the grid
for ix, x in enumerate(gridX):
    plt.axvline(x=x)
for iy, y in enumerate(gridY): 
    plt.axhline(y=y)

#iterate the grid
for gridPosX in gridX:
    for gridPosY in gridY:
        inCell = lambda x,y: (gridPosX<x and x<gridPosX+gridSize 
                              and gridPosY<y and y<gridPosY+gridSize)

        pointsInCell = [ (x,y) for (x,y) in zip(dataX, dataY) if inCell(x,y)]
        if len(pointsInCell) > 0:
            xPos, yPos = zip(*pointsInCell)
            plt.plot(np.mean(xPos), np.mean(yPos), 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: @vinita If this works for you, it would be nice if you'd accept this answer.

Comment: is it possible to store all the points `[np.mean(xPos), np.mean(yPos)]` rather than plot & show. Because for a million points I cant plot them all. So Id rather save them in a list.

Comment: sure, just create two lists before the loop `meansX = []; meansY = []` and instead of ploting append to the lists `meansX.append(np.mean(xPos))`. Or add them to one list as tuples. Depends on what you need it for. But i think you can figure this out yourself. :)

Comment: Ive another similar query if you can please help me with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211032/how-to-interpolate-excel-file-of-unordered-coordinates-to-a-grid